# Nodemcu Lua ESP8266 not sending TCP sockets using IP address

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, lua, nodemcu

I have recently bought a NodeMcu Lua (Lolin) and I am making some tests with it.
What I have tried to do is send a TCP packet to a php script I have on my server, If I try to send the packet using port and hostname it works, but if I try with IP it doesn't, is this a bug or what?

This is just a test because what I actually need to do is use this board to send TCP packets to a php script I have on my pc (so in the same network) running with XAMPP.

Why the board doesn't send any packet using IP but does typing the hostname?
Also what addresses I need to use to send packets from the board to my computer (both in the php script that acts as a server and the board which acts as a client)?

This is the LUA code I am using for the board:

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("Alice-49289348", "mypassword")
wifi.sta.connect()

Disp = "D1"
Port = 9863
HostIP = "81.139.206.12"

conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
conn:on("receive", function(conn, c) print(c) end )
conn:on("connection", function(conn, c)
    print("Connected")
    conn:send(Disp)
    end )
conn:on("sent", function(conn, c)
    print("Sent: " .. Disp)
    conn:close()
    end )
conn:connect(Port,HostIP)

print("Done")
```

I have changed some values like IP address, wifi, password etc for privacy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can obtain feedback using "reconnection", "disconnection" events. 
https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/net/#netsocketon

Also, this function may help to verify the correctness of ip.
https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/net/#netsocketdns